# Open link in a certain div and replace div image on html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get one link to open in a certain **div**.

When click on Jump link I need open the link on **div id="container"** and replace the image on the div with the webpage.

I have tried this code without success.

How to do resolve this?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
function finish(){
    document.getElementById("loading").style.visibility = "hidden";
}


$(document).ready(function () {

  $('input[readonly]').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
        var aID = $(this).attr('href');
        var elem = $(''+aID).html();

        $('.target').html(elem);
    });
});

</script>


<ul class="sub_menu">
   <li><a name="#container" href="http://...">Jump</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="container" >
   <img src="images/Logo.jpg" />     
</div>
```

**#EDIT01**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

function showPanel() {
            document.getElementById('image').style.display = "none";
}

</script>


<ul class="sub_menu"">
   <li><a name="#container" href="http://..." target="content" onclick="showPanel()">Jump</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="image">
   <img src="images/Logo.jpg" />    
      <iframe name="content" style="border:none;">
      </iframe>      
</div>
```

Comment: Did you forget to post your javascript code?

Comment: @teukkam I don't have javascript code, I'm sorry

Comment: Could you please explain more about your query

Comment: @SourabhSomani I have find this example on Google, but I understand that is incomplete ....

Comment: @SourabhSomani Please see edit in question

Comment: @teukkam Please see edit in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use iframe?

```js
function showPanel() {
   document.getElementById('image').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<ul class="sub_menu">
   <li><a name="#container" href="www.example.com" target="content" onclick="showPanel()">Jump</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="container" >
<img src="https://camo.mybb.com/e01de90be6012adc1b1701dba899491a9348ae79/687474703a2f2f7777772e6a71756572797363726970742e6e65742f696d616765732f53696d706c6573742d526573706f6e736976652d6a51756572792d496d6167652d4c69676874626f782d506c7567696e2d73696d706c652d6c69676874626f782e6a7067" id="image">
   <iframe name="content" style="border:none;">
   </iframe>
</div>
```

**Answer for edit #1:** Your edit #01 is not working because you are hiding the entire div by id "image". Change div id to another name.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

function showPanel() {
            document.getElementById('image').style.display = "none";
}

</script>


<ul class="sub_menu">
   <li><a name="#container" href="example.com" target="content" onclick="showPanel()">Jump</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="images">
   <img src="images/Logo.jpg" id="image" />    
      <iframe name="content" style="border:none;">
      </iframe>      
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have tried your code. The iframe not load. Please see #Edit01 in my first question

Comment: Your edit #1 is not working because you are hiding the entire div by id "image". Change div id to another name. Check my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can create `iframe` on the fly and place it inside `container` div.

```js
$('.sub_menu').on('click', 'li > a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#container').html('<iframe class="myiframe" src="'+url+'" />');
})
```

```css
.myiframe{border: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sub_menu">
   <li><a name="#container" href="/questions">Jump</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="container" >
   <img src="images/Logo.jpg" />     
</div>
```